# permission denied in running script

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I am running a script but there is an unusual warning:
This is what happened in my console

```
#whoami
root
#ls -l test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1894 Feb  2 01:58 test.sh*
#./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

Edit:
my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read pass port user ip file; do
  echo "startt------------------------------------" $ip
  ping $ip -c 4
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $ip ok...
  else
    echo $ip failed...
  fi
  echo "finish------------------------------------" $ip
done <<____HERE
pass  22  root  1.1.1.1  test.txt
____HERE
```

any idea?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am running the script in /tmp directory
as you see the result of ls is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1894 Feb  2 01:58 test.sh*
```

there is `.` after permissions which indicates that an SELinux security context applies to that file. so I copied test.sh in a directory else...

the problem was solved

I was in a directory where it might be a bad idea for executables to reside

```
ls -l /
drwxrwxrwt.   8 root root  1024 Feb  2 07:44 tmp/
```

These may work as well:

```
setenforce 0 | reboot
```

OR

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce | reboot
```

OR:

```
putting SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config and reboot (making sure to comment out anything in that file enabling selinux)
```

SELINUX status:  `sestatus`

Comment: Disabling SElinux just to run a script might not be a good idea...

Comment: Copying a file is like creating a new one, so there are a couple of options.  1) Try restorecon /tmp/test.sh after you copied it.  That could work if the file context is generic enough.  2) Run ls -lZ on the original test.sh, get the context, and then set that context with 'chcon' if the first option didn't work.

Comment: "I was in a directory where it might be a bad idea for executables to reside"